# how i can set position of python output screen (that black output screen appears on double tapping the python file) to where I want, on my monitor

Tags: python, python-idle

I want to change the position of my output screen of python to anywhere I want on my display monitor, please help.

I need a function, something like (X and Y parameter) which I can set to move the output screen on wherever I want it to be on my computer screen

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, you can use the [`win32gui`](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/) module:

```
import win32gui

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 300, 500, True)
```

The code above would move the command-prompt to the top-left corner of the screen, and  resize it to be 300 pixels in width and 500 pixels in height. Do note that your screen might have an invisible border, so you might need to offset coordinates a bit to make up for the border:

```
import win32gui

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, -7, 0, 300, 500, True)
```

Comment: My answer would have been that by design, user code cannot modify IDLE, with only stdlib modules as delivered, I believe that to be true.  Thanks for adding a better answer, with an easy install, which is not restricted to IDLE, and which will do much more than just reposition the window.